# Javascript Object - using jQuery and this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this, javascript-objects

When using jQuery methods within an object function (ie - .each()), the "this" variable is then referencing the object being iterated over.  How can I access the Object's functions without "this"?  I realize that's a bit confusing, so:

```
test.prototype.init = function(node) {
    node.children().each(function() {
        //call test.anotherFunction() here
        //Would normally call this.anotherFunction(), 
        //  but "this" refers to the current child.
    });
}
test.prototype.anotherFunction = function() {
    //whatever
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save a copy of `this` into a local variable (named `self` in this example, but you can name it anything you want) and use the saved copy in your embedded function:

```
test.prototype.init = function(node) {
    var self = this;
    node.children().each(function() {
        // use self here to reference the host object
    });
}
test.prototype.anotherFunction = function() {
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: +1 `var self = this;` is often used to keep the parent's scope.

Comment: I prefer `var that = this;` as `self` shadows the global `window.self`

Comment: echoing @jbabey's concern over `self`.

Comment: *facepalm*  I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Would there be any concerns over using 'obj'?  Makes my brain happier than 'that'.

Comment: `self` or `that` or `obj` is all personal style/choice.  I don't have a conflict with `window.self` because if I need `window.self`, I always refer to it as `window.self` (just like I refer to `window.location`) which is separate from the local variable `self`.

Comment: `window.self` refers to the `window` context. So it makes sense to shadow it with the current context.

Answer (score 3):

You could also make use of the `.bind` function to change the context of the function. Whatever argument you provide to `.bind` will become the owner of the function when it executes, and thus, the value of `this`.

```
test.prototype.init = function(node) {
    node.children().each(function(i,el) {
        // this = test.prototype
        // i = index of the current child of `node`
        // el = HTML node of current child
        // $(el) = jQuery object representing current child
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: using bind is a nice approach

Answer (score 1):

You can define the object that you want to refer to before iterating. You'll be able to approach it, as it's still in scope.

```
var currentObject = this;

test.prototype.init = function(node) {
    node.children().each(function() {
        currentObject.anotherFunction();
    });
}
test.prototype.anotherFunction = function() {
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: The whole point of methods on an object is that you can reference the object that the method was called on.  Setting a global variable before you make a method call rather than just using the actual object reference in the method is not a good style and is prone to all sorts of potential problems.